# Using clrLoading for a list of buttons

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am using a VMWare Clarity datagrid where one column has a button. I would like that when I click on a button, that one has the spinner, but not the other ones. How could I manage to isolate that behavior?

```
  <clr-datagrid [clDgRowSelection]="true" [(clrDgSingleSelected)]="itemSelected">

    <clr-dg-column>Title</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>&nbsp;</clr-dg-column>

    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let item of items; trackBy: trackById" [clrDgItem]="item">
      <clr-dg-cell>{{ item.name }}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>
        <button [clrLoading]="resetState" type="button" class="btn btn-sm" (click)="resetItem(item)"</clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>

  </clr-datagrid>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to try to answer that, but I first want to point out that you are using `[clDgRowSelection]="true"` with a button inside the row. That's something Clarity doesn't support because you are nesting buttons inside of buttons. It is simply not valid HTML, so you're going to have strange bugs with this.

Comment: Did not know that row selection was already a button, but that explain why when clicking on my button, the row get selected at the same time. Thanks for the clarification @Eudes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to make you you have a "loading" state **for each item**.
It could be that `item.resetState` is `true` while it's reseting, or you could turn your `resetState` into a map rather than a simple boolean.

For instance, the second solution I mentioned would look like:

```
<button [clrLoading]="resetState[item.id]" (click)="resetItem(item)">
```

where `resetItem(item)` does the reset and sets `resetState[item.id] = true` while waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks @Eudes